# how to detect bottleneck from response time performance testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Response time for a particular transaction increased between two runs of jmeter tests. How to detect the bottleneck in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you ask could fill volumes, for each architectural platform and each type of software you have in use.  There are some rules of thumb that can distill the problem you have.

Ultimately scalability is a problem of resources and their use in the machine, particularly finite resources...when you allocate them...how much you use of them...when you release them....   The top level core finite resources are CPU, Disk, Memory and Network.  You can derive hundreds of sub resources off of those, such as file handles under memory, swap utilization under disk, system & application under CPU, Error retransmits under network, etc...

To understand where your bottleneck exists is to first identify the resource which is being impinged at the time of your slowdown.   From there it is to understand the code which accesses said resource during the window in question and then finally which segment of code is the critical section. Tools such as Dynatrace, NewRelic, Wiley and the like have made a business model over helping to track the internal details of the app, but you still need to line up the clocks and response times for the time of the incident.

Monitoring is key and critical. Unfortunately this is an area which has been left wanting in much of the open source world.  Let us just throw load!  Integrated monitoring?  Well, go get a plug in and fit it in for that stuff.   This is the area where the commercial tools have all of the open source tools beat hands down. And then the analysis follows on to view the integration of the monitoring data with the response data...

Since you are looking at one particular response time in your test this does become a bit easier still.  If you are not a part of development then go to the dev team and ask for a list of all of the code changes from your last tested build.  Next, you need to highlight in this list which ones are called during the time of your particular timed event which has increased in time.   From there if you have a picture of which resource has increased then you can quickly scan the code for items directly related to the use of a particular resource.  For instance, if DISK has increased then perhaps someone checked in code with DEBUG level logging enabled and you have a drag anchor of writes to the disk.  It could be that connection handles to some object are not being cleaned as fast so you have a memory issue in play.

Hopefully this provides some sort of path for you to examine the possibilities

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info James.. :)